# Adding column to books table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how am i able to add a column to my books table in rails? i want to do this through a migration

This is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160716030811) do

    create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by running a migration. It depends on what column you want to add. I see you have a name column already, so if you were to create a description column, run `rails generate migration AddDescriptionToBooks description:string`

If you want to create a different column just replace the 2 `description` words in that migration code with whatever you want

This will create a migration which adds a column `description` to the table.